# .htaccess General Rule for all Pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I take the page var from `http://domain.com/recent?page=2` (the original page is `http://domain.com/?id=recent&page=2`) with .htaccess?  (i need a general rule for all pages) thanx for help

Comment: And what do you need to do with that page var?

Comment: I generate with .htaccess (RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1) this page :http://domain.com/recent (original http://domain.com/?id=recent)  the http://domain.com/recent?page=2  is recent's second page

Comment: Then I am nt sure why do you need .htaccess rule here. You can simply access page var using `$_GET['page']` in your php code.

Comment: I have already done that, but for some reason the variable is empty

Comment: Alright I think I understand your problem now, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Key change is use of `QSA` flag which will preserve original query string even after adding `id=$1`.

Answer (score 1):

It's something like

```
RewriteRule (.+)?page=([0-9]+) ?id=$1&page=$2
```

Take a look at regex and examples you can find on google ;)

Comment: Won't work since QUERY_STRING is not available in RewriteRule.

Comment: Ah true. So he needs to have an url like recent-2 instead of recent?page=2.
EDIT : There is maybe something with [querystrings](http://fantomaster.com/faarticles/rewritingurls.txt) : RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.+)